# Cycles: Glass not rendering as transparent in CPU mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: Node Set up]AMD Ryzen 7 2700 8-core 4.1, 32 GB RAM, RTX 2060 (6GB VRAM)

I have a glass and transparent BSDF set up correctly in Blender, and the texture set to alpha clip, and alpha hashed for shadows. The glass works perfectly in GPU mode but is not showing the image behind it in CPU mode - simply switching from one to the other.

The scene, even with optimisations, is still too large to render on the GPU for my card. Simply switching from GPU to CPU to allow for rendering the image results in the glass/transparnet shader no longer being see-through.

Is this a bug or is there something I have missed?[image: GPU vs CPU Transparent Render]

Comment: Could you share your material setup?

Comment: Yes I could but it's simply a glass shader, and a transparent shader mixed going into the surface. Neither the glass or the Transparent on their own work in CPU mode. They are fine in GPU mode. Why would that be?

Comment: How do you mix them? What is the difference between the image on the left and the image on the right? If the scene is too large, how do you know it looks fine on the GPU? Would be easier if you’d share the file or give us a little more information.

Comment: Scene on the left has the image passing through the glass (GPU mode) and the scene on the right does not. They are being mixed simply with a mix shader. It does not matter whether they are mixed or not. Neither the glass shader or the transparent shader work in CPU mode. The issue is not the shaders, it is that CPU mode is not working for rendering a texture transparent.

Comment: WRT the image passing through the glass - the image is an "image as plane" of clouds. I am trying to transition to cycles from Eevee and experimenting with work flows. The model is of a steampunk airship cabin and you are looking at the circular observation window. The ONLY difference between the scene on the left and right is whether it was rendered in CPU mode or GPU.

Comment: If you could at least add a screenshot of the node setup & material settings, that could go a long way here.  No one can answer this question based on just the CPU/GPU tidbit of info, that's not nearly enough detail to figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: Ok, I will do this, but as I explained in my post...simply a glass shader OR a transparent shader connected directly to the surface, with NO other shaders or anything gives the same result. It's the first thing I tried. Simply a glass shader, or a transparent shader works in GPU mode but NOT in CPU mode.

There are no other materials involved.

Comment: I have added a node set up to the post. Note: I tried with the material output setting to "all", and I took this screengrab while experimenting setting it to cycles. It made no difference. Also it makes no difference whether I use CUDA or Optix - both work, but CPU only does not.

Comment: Could you share your Blender file?

Comment: Not really...it is a commercial model and the file size is over 1 Gb. What I will do today is do some tests in a blend file with just basic shapes and textures. If it doesn't work there I will share that as well.

Comment: After doing some tests, I have been able to create a simple scene with glass and transparent shaders working with CPU. Note; viewport de-noising crashes Blender instantly in CPU mode. I still don't have any idea as to why the scene I am playing with will not render transparent surfaces in CPU mode.

Comment: @DrIgnatiusCole, at least you could post a blend just with the glass object and its material! But just for confirmation: Does this glass has some volume (front and back faces) or is it just a single surface? the last don't work well with the glass shader, since the engine assumes everything before or after the surface (depending in the normals) to be inside glass.

Comment: That's a good idea...I'll do that. That's a step I should have taken trouble-shooting anyway. To answer your question, YES, I added some thickness with the default setting of the solidify modifier. It still doesn't explain why in both GPU modes, Optix and Cuda, the surface works as expected, but in CPU mode it does not. I'll post a blend file with just the elements affected later today. Good idea.

Comment: Your setup works for me under CPU ... [Preview](https://imgur.com/G5Gt1UT) Does this [blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/NlKxJKRj/) works for you? If it doesn't work for you, it can be graphics card.

Comment: Hi vklidu, thanks for this. I actually set up a simple test file and switching between CPU and GPU worked fine for me as well. So it must be something in the file I was working with. I will try to get extract the relevant bits and post later today.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help your problem but you shouldn't use glass and transparent shader mix, instead, for realistic results, use Principled BSDF with transmission of 1, if you're using eevee, you will need to enable screen space reflections and refraction in render settings, check refraction checkbox in material settings and set refraction depth to something other than 0.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment. Using glass and transparent shader together works fine in cycles (and Eevee) and allows to control the density of the texture of the glass shader. In this case I have a glass scratches texture which on it's own would be too strong. If I use a glass shader I can control the refraction angle.

The issue here really is that everything works fine in GPU mode but not CPU. This was true whether I used transparent or glass shader on their own. I will try to post the elements later today and see if anyone can replicate.